# groupby results in empty datafram

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

**Issue:**

groupby on below data, resulted in empty dataframe, not sure how to fix, please help thanks.

**data:**

```
business_group business_unit cost_center GL_code profit_center count
NaN            a             12          12-09   09            1
NaN            a             12          12-09   09            1
NaN            b             23          23-87   87            1
NaN            b             23          23-87   87            1
NaN            b             34          34-76   76            1
```

**groupby:**

```
group_df = df.groupby(['business_group', 'business_unit','cost_center','GL_code','profit_center'],
           as_index=False).count()
```

**expected result:**

```
business_group business_unit cost_center GL_code profit_center count
NaN            a             12          12-09   09            2
NaN            b             23          23-87   87            2
NaN            c             34          34-76   76            1
```

**result received**:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [business_group, business_unit, cost_center, GL_code, profit_center, count]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `NaN` in `business_group` is the null values, and `groupby()` by default will drop all `NaN` values. You can pass `dropna=False` into `groupby()`:

```
group_df = df.groupby(['business_group', 'business_unit',
                       'cost_center','GL_code','profit_center'],dropna=False,
                       as_index=False).count()
```

Output:

```
   business_group business_unit  cost_center GL_code  profit_center  count
0             NaN             a           12   12-09              9      2
1             NaN             b           23   23-87             87      2
2             NaN             b           34   34-76             76      1
```